# Why can't we make our own fundamental particles?

Tags: particle-physics, atomic-physics

Why can't we make our own fundamental particles ?Is it because we haven't figured out what the most rudimentary particle is made up of?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're asking. What do you mean by "our own fundamental particles"? And what do you mean by "most rudimentary particle" if you apparently suppose it is *made up of something else*, making it not the "most rudimentary" by the ordinary meaning of the word?

Comment: You might like to read about "quasiparticles" and their connection to the fundamental particles in the vacuum. An amusing book on the subject is "A Different Universe" by Laughlin.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't we make our own fundamental particles ?

We do all the time at places like CERN/LHC, but they decay very quickly. I don’t know what you mean by “our own” exactly. If you mean making a new fundamental particle that has never been detected, then we are trying to do this in the search for [superpartners](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superpartner) described by [supersymmetry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry). Otherwise if you mean “custom made fundamental particles”, then how could they be described as elementary or fundamental? The [standard model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics lists all the fundamental particles and there properties/interactions etc.

However, during the particle collisions observed on a daily basis at such facilities, we may find a particle we have never even hypothesised, and in such an instance, I guess you could say that we have “made a fundamental particle”.

> Is it because we haven't figured out what the most rudimentary particle is made up of?

Assuming the elementary particles are indeed not elementary (they have further substructure), then you are right and we actually do not know what the elementary particles are made of. But there are theories, the most popular being [string theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory).

Answer (score 1):

The **fundamental** particles are the building blocks. They are called fundamental, because there is nothing else. Therefore, it is impossible to make up our own fundamental particles. However, since the nuclei of atoms are not fundamental, it is possible to create new "atoms". This is done using particles colliders.

Suppose the universe consists of three spatial and one temporal dimension.  If this is true, it is impossible to access a fourth spatial dimension. No matter how hard we try, we are unable to make up our own fourth spatial dimension. This example is similar to the question you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the way you think of „fundamental“. And, unfortunately, your question is not very precise in that respect. Thus, I try to give an answer based on what I personally read from your question (I may have gone wrong completely...)

Consider we turn an existing fundamental particle into another new particle that did not yet exist in the universe. It is, obviously, a particle allowed to exist in accordance with the laws of nature. Just because it has never been produced by any physical process *yet* does not mean it is a particle *new* to the laws of nature.

It is known that we have not completely uncovered the true laws of nature yet and may have missed the possible existence of new fundamental particles. But as soon as we produce a new particle, we can tell that our laws need to be revised.

This goes on until (maybe never) we find the correct laws and by that uncover all fundamental particles allowed to exist in accordance with those laws. But we may still not be able, technically, to produce them all.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't we make our own fundamental particles ?

[The etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=fundament%20) of fundamental comes from "fundament" " So called because it is where one sits." The foundation of a building, for example.

So the fundamental particles in the theory of the [Standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)  , SM, are part of the  the building blocks on which the which the theory is mathematically built up, extra axioms, to pick up the correct solutions from the mathematics, so that data can be described and predicted.

> Is it because we haven't figured out what the most rudimentary particle is made up of?

It is because the specific model, the SM, fits the data and allows predictions for new  observations. If new data come up with future observations and experiments, there may be a revision of the SM, or a new SM, which could have more elementary particles but it would have to fit the already existing data.

It may be that progress in understanding the observations and data will lead to a theory that has one fundamental particle, as is the case if a string theory manages  to become the theory of everything, where the string theory  fundamental particle is the string and  the SM particles are excitations on the string.

Still the constraint is **the data and the ability to predict new observations** that will characterize any new model.

Mathematics allows a practically infinite number of possibilities to "create/assume" particles. It is observations and data that pick up the specific SM or the future standard model particles  .